# ROS2 DDS communication: How to connect AWS EC2 Instance remotely

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to connect from a Client PC (Raspberry Pi) to an AWS EC2 Instance remotely over the internet using by UDP unicast.

I had set up both computers as below.I executed a "**ros2 run demo_nodes_py talker**" on this Client PC, and executed a "**ros2 run demo_nodes_py listener**" on this Instance. But this Instance cannot receive topic messageses from this Client PC. Please let me know how to connect AWS EC2 Instance.

Details information is below:

**AWS EC2 Instance configuration**

- TYPE: AWS EC2 VPC Instance(t2.micro)
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- ROS Version: ROS2 Dashing Diademata
- Private IP: aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa
- Public IP: bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb
- FastRTPS - DEFAULT_FASTRTPS_PROFILES.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<profiles>
    <participant profile_name="my_profile_s" is_default_profile="true">
        <rtps>
            <builtin>
                <metatrafficUnicastLocatorList>
                    <locator/>
                </metatrafficUnicastLocatorList>
                <initialPeersList>
                    <locator>
                        <udpv4>
                            <address>ddd.ddd.ddd.ddd</address>
                        </udpv4>
                    </locator>
                </initialPeersList>
            </builtin>
        </rtps>
    </participant>
</profiles>
```

- AWS EC2 Security Group Inbound Configuration

```
type      : port number: src address
-----------------------------------
Custom UDP: port 7412  : 0.0.0.0/0
Custom UDP: port 7413  : 0.0.0.0/0
Custom UDP: port 7414  : 0.0.0.0/0
Custom UDP: port 7415  : 0.0.0.0/0
Custom UDP: port 7416  : 0.0.0.0/0
```

**Client PC configuration**

- TYPE: Raspberry Pi 3+
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- ROS Version: ROS 2 Dashing Diademata
- Private IP: ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc
- Public IP: ddd.ddd.ddd.ddd
- FastRTPS - DEFAULT_FASTRTPS_PROFILES.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<profiles>
    <participant profile_name="my_profile_c" is_default_profile="true">
        <rtps>
            <builtin>
                <metatrafficUnicastLocatorList>
                    <locator/>
                </metatrafficUnicastLocatorList>
                <initialPeersList>
                    <locator>
                        <udpv4>
                            <address>bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb</address>
                        </udpv4>
                    </locator>
                </initialPeersList>
            </builtin>
        </rtps>
    </participant>
</profiles>
```

Thank you in advance for reading my question.

Best regards,

Iori

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328770/ros2-dds-communication:-how-to-connect-aws-ec2-instance-remotely/) by [Iori](https://answers.ros.org/users/44080/iori/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-07-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kaliatech](https://answers.ros.org/users/5440/kaliatech/) on 2019-07-26**:
Fwiw, I have also been unable to get UDP unicast to work.  However, I was able to get TCP to work from client to EC2 server.  Let me know if that configuration would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your advice.

To use UDP unicast communication with ROS2, both client PC and AWS EC2 had to be able to send and receive data using the udp protocol each other. Since this network condition I have asked was client PC communicate AWS EC via NAT, It didn't work UDP unicast communication.

Therefore, I solved this problem by using an **OpenVPN** network between a Client PC and AWS EC2.

Best regards,
Iori

---

Originally posted by [Iori](https://answers.ros.org/users/44080/iori/) with karma: 11 on 2019-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [btidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/140265/btidd/) on 2023-05-18**:
Can I ask how you set up your configuration? With OpenVPN we are able to echo topics on the client PC published on AWS EC2, but not the other way around.